# Mesh coordinates

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have created a cube in blender and I have resized it. When I use the following code to print the coordinates, it prints the coordinates for the original cube (not the resized one). Could you let me know how I can get the coordinates for the resized cube?

```
for item in bpy.data.objects:        
    print(item.name)  
    if item.type == 'MESH':  
        for vertex in item.data.vertices:  
            print(vertex.co)
```

Comment: I think you should apply transforms for the cube first (assume you haven't already)

Comment: I have already transformed the cube by pressing 'S'.

Comment: Applying transforms (`Ctrl`+`A`) is [another command](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply%20transforms#apply-object-transformations), as I assume you scaled your mesh in Object mode

Comment: what you get are coordinates in object space you can avoid applying transformation and  calculate the world coordinates instead

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you need to apply the scale transform you performed. I would do something like:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # deselect everything to avoid a mess
for item in bpy.data.objects:
    print(item.name)
    if item.type == 'MESH':
        item.select = True # lets select every mesh as we go
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True) # apply transform
        item.select = False # we're done working on this object
        for vertex in item.data.vertices:  
            print(vertex.co)
```